# AVX intrinsic and matrix multiplication with c language

Tags: c, matrix, avx

Error message:

> incompatible types when initializing type ‘__m256d {aka __vector(4)
> double}’ using type ‘__m256 {aka __vector(8) float}’
> __m256d c0 = _mm256_setzero_ps();

I was running a c matrix multiplication with AVX intrinsic and i got the error when compiling. I included  <x86intrin.h>

Comment: Probably should be _mm256_setzero_pd() if you're using doubles, or __m256 c0 = .... if you're using 32 bit floats.

Answer (score 2):

There are three relevant data types `__m256` (holds 8 `float`s), `__m256d` (holds 4 `double`s) and `__m256i` (holds 256 bits worth of integers). Each of these has an intrinsic for initialization to zero: `_mm256_setzero_ps`, `_mm256_setzero_pd` and `_mm256_setzero_si256`, respectively. You need to use the correct one according to the variable type.

As a side note, the integer and float/double variant also emit as different instructions, so that a register does not have to cross between integer and FP domains in the CPU. There are minor performance penalties for that - at least there used to be (AFAIK Golden Cove does not have those anymore).